# System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Windows.Size' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm new to web front end development.
I ran into an error that was hard to understand by my ability.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Windows.Size' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'

### Situation

I'm implementing a progress bar linked to two videos using .net core 5.0(Let's name the two videos **A** and **B** respectively.)

When the time of A is updated, the corresponding event(ontimeupdate) is executed and the current time value of the video is put into the value of the progress bar.

At that time, I should to execute **StateHasChanged()** for refreshing progress bar(This means that the **StateHasChanged** function is called once every second)

But after starting the video, after 5~10 seconds elapses, the above error occurs.
So I deleted StateHasChanged() and It works very well, however progress bar is not refreshed.

Page have one table, four line charts(chartjs.Blazor), two videos(Blazored.Video).

### Problem I guess

- Is it caused by upgrading .net core 3.1 to 5.0?
- Is it a problem by drawing too many components at once? (two videos, four charts(draw by chartjs.Blazor))?
- Would it be a problem if StateHasChanged() is called periodically when there is 'chartjs' components?

### code

I'm using [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/), [Blazored.Video](https://github.com/Blazored/Video), [ChartJs.Blazor](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor) Nuget packages

```
-------- razor page --------
<BlazoredVideo PlayEvent="OnPlay" TimeUpdate="OnTimeUpdate"
               VideoEventOptions="options"
               class="w-100"
               style="max-width:800px;"
               controls="controls">
    <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/blazoredgitter/video/upload/v1557015491/samples/elephants.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</BlazoredVideo>

<MatSlider Id="video_slider" @bind-Value="@currentVideoDuration" Discrete="true" Pin="true" TValue="int" ValueMin="0" ValueMax="100"></MatSlider>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ChartJsLineChart @ref="_lineChartJs" Config="@lineConfig1" Width="600" Height="300" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ChartJsLineChart @ref="_lineChartJs" Config="@lineConfig2" Width="600" Height="300" />
    </div>
</div>


-------- cs code(code behind) --------

public LineConfig lineConfig1;
public LineConfig lineConfig2;
public ChartJsLineChart _lineChartJs;

Dictionary<VideoEvents, VideoStateOptions> options = new Dictionary<VideoEvents, VideoStateOptions>();
public int currentVideoDuration;

var option = new VideoStateOptions() { All = true };
     
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()       
{
    var option = new VideoStateOptions() { All = true };
    
    options[VideoEvents.Pause] = option;
    options[VideoEvents.Play] = option;
    options[VideoEvents.Playing] = option;
    options[VideoEvents.Progress] = option;
    options[VideoEvents.TimeUpdate] = new VideoStateOptions() { CurrentTime = true };
    currentVideoDuration = 0;

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

public void OnTimeUpdate(VideoState state)
{
    currentVideoDuration = (int)state.CurrentTime;
    StateHasChanged();  <-- caused error
}

//line chart configuration.. and set chart datas
```

Sorry for bad English. It's too difficult to solve this for me. Someone please help me.

### Edit

While using Blazored.Video and ChartJS.blazor at the same time, I found out that this is a problem if the **StateHasChanged** function is called periodically.

I tested it .net core 3.1, 5.0 with new project
I installed package to need only
And I tested with page which have just one video or just one chart(It worked well)

However, although I found the problem, I couldn't solve it by my abillity. I think I should to change a one of two packages or both.. :(

Comment: Could you show where you're using the `Size` class? It seems that you're importing a DLL (WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0) which is not compatible with Blazor. Have you manually added WindowsBase as a reference in your project?

Comment: @arconaut Thank you for your caring. I never used `Size` class(At least as far as I know...). I added all packages by Nuget Manager. I'll find out if there are any manually added references.

Comment: According to the [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/Slider) and [Blazored Video](https://github.com/Blazored/Video) documents, I have created a sample using asp.net core 3.1 and 5.0 version, it seems that they all works well on my side, can't reproduce the problem, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDQUp.gif). I searched some resource, it seems that this issue might be related to the OS or Visual Studio(VS) update, so try to repair the VS and update the OS and VS to the latest version.

Comment: @ZhiLv Did you test ChartJS and Blazored video? I've tested MatBlazor and Blazored video as well. But as I mentioned in 'Edit', It occurs while using Blazored.Video and Chart.JS together.

Comment: @takeyourcode, Yes, in my sample, I'm using MatBlazor, Blazored.Video and the Chart.JS together, on the same page. They all work well, doesn't meet any issue.

Comment: @ZhiLv Very Thanks!! I'll try it you mentioned.

Comment: @ZhiLv hmm... I tried it several way to retry after windows and visual studio update, however I keep getting same error. If chart has a few datas, It works well but my page get four charts and they have a lot of datas. I think it is related to datas quantities. I took another library to draw chart, it is worked well. Anyway, I'm really thanks to your caring!

Comment: @ZhiLv Sorry for my misunderstand. Right, It was my mistake. I used 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell' package, and it conflict with another package I think. I use this package to get video's duration. I should to change how to implementation. Really Thanks guys.

Comment: @takeyourcode Glad to hear that it does help solve the problem, hope you will solve the problem soon.